# MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification gets called when it shouldn't

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

According to Apple's MPMoviePlayerController doc:

MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification -
This notification is not sent in cases where the movie player is displaying in fullscreen mode and the user taps the Done button.

Seems to me this is dead wrong. Using the code below, playerPlaybackDidFinish gets called when I tap the done button.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerPlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.player];

- (void) playerPlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"WHY?");
    self.player.fullscreen = NO;
}
```

I need to distinguish between the user tapping the done button and the movie finishing all the way through playback. playerPlaybackDidFinish does get called when the movie ends, but like I said it also gets called when you tap Done.

Comment: can't you capture the event on the done button?

Comment: I don't think so. It's part of the MPMoviePlayer and there's no callback for it.

Comment: I am having same situation, please help!

Answer (score 22):

Here is how you check the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey which is part of the notification of MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification

```
- (void) playbackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    int reason = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];
    if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
        //movie finished playin
    }else if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) {
        //user hit the done button
    }else if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError) {
        //error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using the following to do something when a movie is played all the way to the end:

```
- (void)playbackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    BOOL playbackEnded = ([[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue] == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded);
    BOOL endReached = (self.player.currentPlaybackTime == self.player.playableDuration);

    if (playbackEnded && endReached) {
        // Movie Ended
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you get the notification you can check the player's endPlaybackTime. If it's -1 then the movie finished all the way back naturally.

For streamed content, you can check the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey inside the userInfo on the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification.

If it's equal to MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited then it's the user stopped playing the content.

Comment: just tried that. self.player.endPlaybackTime is -1 whether you close via Done button or if it plays all the way through. Checked the documentation - "This property is not applicable for streamed content."

Comment: Oh I'm not aware you're talking about streamed content.... I've revised my answer

Comment: This seems like a great idea, but if ([[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey"] intValue] == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) always returns false, whether I click Done or if the user ends naturally.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure for

```
    moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
```