# MPMoviePlayerController sends "end of movie reached" when URL is changed

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotifications

I'm trying to get a notification from a MPMoviePlayerController when the movie has reached its end. I'm running the player in embedded mode with a local file.

Like the docs suggest, I registered for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification and check if the MPMovieFinishReason key contains the intValue of MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded. That's working fine.

But I get the same notification with MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded when I switch the movie using the contentURL property before it has actually reached its end. So I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158453/mpmovieplayerplaybackdidfinishnotification-gets-called-when-it-shouldnt/4160782#4160782) and checked if endPlaybackTime == -1, but that's true in both cases.

The only workaround I found so far is to remove the observer before changing contentURL and then adding it again, but I think there must be a more elegant solution?

Comment: Are you doing that on background?

Comment: Do you mean on a background thread? No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to work consistently to simply removeObserver, stop playback/change the Url, then addObserver once more.

Comment: Right, it still looks like there is no better solution. I'll accept this answer, although this has been mentioned in the question already ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, per the documentation, your observed behavior seems to be the correct behavior. I think your solution to quit getting notifications might be a good one. Yeah, it's a little hacky, but it seems like it would work.

Alternatively, what about storing the URL of the movie(s) you're playing and comparing against `[moviePlayer contentURL]`? You might have to do some timer acrobatics and have a `currentMovieURL` and a `previousMovieURL`, but that ought to provide a good way to compare if the movie that ended is the movie you expected to end.

Alternatively to **that**, what about setting 2 variables: `movieStartTime` and `expectedMovieDuration`? Then, you can compare `[NSDate date]` to `[movieStartTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:expectedMovieDuration]` and see if it's way off.